# Laravel 5.4 - Deleting specific records from the pivot table

Tags: php, laravel, many-to-many, sql-delete

For each visit I may have many products; therefore the pivot table (product_visit) has the fields:
id, product_id, visit_id, qtd and amount.

To delete a visit and its related records on the pivot table, everything works fine:

```
 public function getVisitDelete($id){
    $visits = Visit::find($id);
    $visits->products()->detach();
    $visits->delete();
}
```

However, I could not figure out how to delete one specific record from the pivot table using detach or something similar. So I ended up doing the following:

```
public function getProductVisitDelete(){
    $visit_id   =   (int)Request('visit_id');
    $product_id =   (int)Request('product_id');
    $sqlDelete = "delete from product_visit where visit_id=$visit_id and product_id = $product_id";
    DB::select($sqlDelete);
}
```

Though it works, I am far being happy with this solution -- looks like I am missing something.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use `wherePivot()` method to detach specific product from the visit.

```
$visits = Visit::find($visit_id);
$visits->products()->wherePivot('product_id','=',$product_id)->detach();
```

**Update**
As given in [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) "Attaching / Detaching" section, you can pass the related model's id that you want to remove in `detach()` method. Example

```
$visits = Visit::find($id);
$visits->products()->detach($product_id);
```

Comment: The edited example only works as long as you have a product only once attached to the visit.